# How can I scroll only on a part on PC view?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make the same scroll function with this website(https://salanaru.jp/).

On this website, we can scroll only the right side contents.
even if you try to scroll the other parts, the right side contents scroll.

I checked developper tool, but I couldn't find any code that is controlling the scroll function.

How can I find the code or fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed` on the left container and set a width (x).
Use `padding-left: x` on the right container.

```css
body {
 background-color: blue;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 70vw;
}

.right {
  padding-left: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Fixed Content</div>
<div class="right">
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
  <p>Scrolly Content</p>
</div>
```